# Test Google Speech API with audio file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I want to see if Google Speech API will be accurate enough for my purposes. I have an audio file I want to test it with, but the demo on the main page only lets you record from a microphone. Is there a way to test Google's speech processing with an audio file without having to learn the API first?

Answer (score 1):

No, you will have to use the API if you wish to upload a file.

The steps are [described here](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/getting-started#make_a_speech_api_request) on how to make the API request and it is fairly straightforward. The same page also details how to set up your account, enable billing and getting the access token for the request.